# Overriding Style in Custom View Constructor

Tags: android, android-view, android-styles

I am attempting to set the style for a custom view through its constructor. It is not having the intended effect.

*QueueButton.java*

```
public class QueueButton extends ImageButton {
  public QueueButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public QueueButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, R.style.queuebutton);
  }

  public QueueButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, R.style.queuebutton);
  }
}
```

*(in layout)*

```
<QueueButton
  android:id="@+id/queueBtn"
  style="@style/queuebutton"
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="35dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:focusable="false"
  android:src="@drawable/remove_queue_icon" />
```

In the screen capture below, there are three different outcomes.

- Left: The result from the class as described, but without the style declared in XML.
- Middle: The same XML, but with `super(context, attrs)` in the two-argument constructor.
- Right: The result from declaring the style in XML. This is the desired appearance.

Evidently, this is the wrong way to do this. I have not been able to find the relevant information for why that is and how to achieve the appropriate result.

[image: QueueButton results]

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to pass in an attribute and not a style directly.

Add an attribute to your attrs.xml file (or create one in the values folder if you don't have one already). 
Then create a theme for your app and link the new attribute to the required style in that theme (Or just add it to an existing theme if you're already using one).
Finally, in the custom view constructors pass the *attribute* to the super constructor. Android will look for that attribute in the context's theme (as per the documentation), and should use it.
Please note, however that if a style is specified in the XMl it will override the one you use in the constructor, as it takes precedence.

That's how things should look eventually:

attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="queueButtonStyle" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

styles.xml:

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
     <item name="queueButtonStyle">@style/queuebutton</item>
 </style>
<style name="queuebutton">
    ...content...
</style>
```

And the custom view class constructors:

```
public class QueueButton extends ImageButton {
   public QueueButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
   }

   public QueueButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, R.attr.queueButtonStyle);
   }

   public QueueButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, R.attr.queueButtonStyle);
   }
}
```